# How to hide address fields and just show address lookup on lightning-input-address?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, google-map, address

I am able to use `<lightning-input-address>` to create a way to use address lookup functionality to prepopulate address fields. However, we want to hide the address fields and just show the `address lookup`.

Goal:

1. Hide fields in the red box within the image

[image: red box with fields to hide]

Question:

1. How can I hide the address fields and only show the address lookup portion of the `<lightning-input-address>`?

What I tried but didn't work:

```
<lightning-input-address
        show-address-lookup
        field-level-help="Help Text for inputAddress field" ></lightning-input-address>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this is a feature for that component. If your goal is to just prevent editing the values after it filled in then you can use the read-only attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can always hide fields with css. Here's how I just hid the country field:

```
.slds-form-element[data-field="country"]{
display:none;
}
```

it worked like a charm!